# SQL SELECT date from 10 days ago failed

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm havig some trouble with SQL:

First, I insert the current date, using PHP-time():

```
mysql_query("
   INSERT INTO applicants (
      date_last_applied
   )
   VALUES (
      " . time() . "
   )
");
```

This works just fine. However, I only want to execute an action when that ^ was inserted 10 days ago:

```
$result = mysql_query("
   SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE date_last_applied < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    echo $row['id_member'];
```

Although it *should* work (IMO), it doesn't. D:

For possible solutions: it's not an option to use an other timeformat, because I'm using this format on my entire site.

Comment: Should work vs. actually works -- hoping and praying vs. unit-testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for your help, y'all.
This code works flawlessly:

```
 //get member's info
$result = mysql_query("
   SELECT * FROM DDFS_applicants 
   WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date_last_applied, '%Y %D %M') = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)), '%Y %D %M')
");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['id_member'];
```

(So it works *even* to check if the date is the exact same date. If you want, you can even add hours to it, but I chose not to.)

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub

Answer (score 3):

i think converting the date_sub resutl to unixtime will resolve your problem.

```
date_last_applied < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns all rows when the WHERE is true on all rows, but returns none if only one row is true. :/ I also tried converting them both to UNIX_TIMESTAMP, but that failed, too.

Answer (score 1):

while inserting rows you are using time (time()) of the local machine. But while retrieving rows you are using the mysql server's time (NOW()). Are you sure they match exactly and will continue to do so. You should try to use mysql server time everywhere.

Also you are inserting rows in applicants and retrieving from DDFS_applicants. May be that is the problem here

Comment: I haven't had any problems using this time-format until now.. @ your last option: that was a typo, sorry. That part was correct in my original code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a timestamp, and I'm guessing that you don't use a Data time field, Converting should solve your problem. But there is a but!

The UNIX_TIMESTAMP is always in GMT, so it could be that your PHP time() isn't the same as your UNIX_TIMESTAMP. If you find out its the same, then you should be good!

```
date_last_applied < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the same. It doesn't matter as much anyway by the way, because your code just returns everything or nothing (everything when **all** rows were made *days ago* and **none** when ONE row was made *days ago*, while I've got two entries of which one is one day ago and another is three days ago. This is quite a big difference, so it should work anyway.